# Windows Won't Start - Help Analyzing CBS.log please

Tags: windows-7, windows, boot, start-screen, sfc

Good day,

Helping a friend with Windows load issue where I'm receiving STOP: c000021a error blue screen of death while Windows is loading.  Following online instructions, I've run sfc /scannow operation and have a CBS.log but don't know what it means and what I need to do to fix it.  I'm hoping someone can take a look at this and advise how to repair.  Of particular note, I see the repetitive entry "CSI    000000b2 [SR] Cannot repair member file [l:18{9}]"winpe.bmp" ....." I have manually replaced the file but still no joy.

Due to the character count limitation of stack exchange, here is the external link to the log file:

http://www.phoeteo.com/CBSlog.txt

Computer is a Toshiba Satellite laptop running Windows 7 (Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7600])

Any and all help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: We need the entire and exact stop error message.

Comment: What are the full BSOD error messages? [BlueScreenView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/blue_screen_view.html) should provide this information. Please [edit] your question to include this.